# How to disable undo (only from keyboard shortcut) in TinyMCE v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using TinyMCE v5 inline editor.
I want to disable undo/redo **only for keyboard shortcuts** i.e. Command+Z and Command+Shift+Z

*Below is my code*

```
class TextBlock extends Component {

    handleChange = (newText) => {
       *** updating state with newText
    };

    handleBeforeAddUndo = () => {
        **** commented below code because it restricts undo/redo even on undo button click. I dont want that.**
        // return false; 
    };

    handleUndo = (args) => {
       // nothing here
    };

    render() {
        const { content } = this.props.block;
        return (
                <Editor
                    value={content}
                    inline={true}
                    tinymceScriptSrc={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'}
                    init={{
                        height: 500,
                        menubar: false,
                        block_formats: 'Heading1=h1; Heading2=h2; Heading3=h3; Paragraph=p;',
                        plugins: ['lists link paste'],
                        setup: function (editor) {
                          
                            **NOTE: below i tried 'meta+z' but it doesn't work.**
                            editor.addShortcut('meta+g', 'custom undo', () => {
                                console.log('you pressed cmd+z');
                            });
                        },
                        toolbar1:
                            'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic link | forecolor backcolor |',
                        toolbar2:
                            'bullist numlist outdent indent| alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | removeformat',
                    }}
                    onEditorChange={(newText) => this.handleChange(newText)}
                    onBeforeAddUndo={this.handleBeforeAddUndo}
                    onUndo={this.handleUndo}
                />
        );
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this use case? Thank you all for the valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the documentation I would try to set `hasRedo():Boolean` and `hasUndo():Boolean` values to `false`. Please try and tell does it work in your case?

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.undomanager/#hasredo

```
setup : function(editor) {        
    editor.UndoManager.hasUndo(false)
    editor.UndoManager.hasRedo(false)
};
```

Comment: Thankyou @Mile Mijatović for the reply. Can you please tell me how to set hasRedo() in my case ?

Comment: I tried the above solution But this didn't solve my problem

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasUndo')`
getting this error